# Get row letter from value

Tags: python-3.x, gspread

I am trying to get the row letter from a value, my sheet is made up like this:

```
  id    name    level    xp
A 1     yeet    5        10000
```

I need something that will take the id and find the row number like:

```
return get_row(id=1)
```

Then it returns a for example, then clear that row, I hope I explained it well, reply any question. Sorry for being new :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, I can grab the cell using `worksheet.find(id)` than use that cell to delete its row, took me a while to connect the commands on the docs